# Postman to C#(Restsharp) code snippet issue

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I am feeling pretty stupid right now I can not figure this out. I am using postman to generate some C#(Rest sharp) to post a file to a restAPI.

In postman it works file the code snippet that it generates for C# does not work. The response code shows an  internal server error in C#. I can not figure out where the problem is.

Here is the code snippet.

```
client = new RestClient("https://login.mydgsi.ca/WebAPI/Attachment?aboutType=Candidate&referenceID=1314180%20&attachmentTypeID=Resume&Name=Resume&expirationDate=1900/01/01&Note=Candidate%20REeume");

request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "b339e68d-9257-44eb-8698-1f3f0c86ebfe");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + secruityToken.access_token);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\jbungay\\Documents\\MyJabberFiles\\ddemchuk@domain.not.set\\3vertical Number 1 Resume.docx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Here is fiddler shows on the postman post. I am new to Fiddler and Postman.

[Screen of the inspector from Fidder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4VWY.png)

Comment: Check the fiddler traces difference between C# code and Postman request. As mentioned you get Internal Server Error so it seems to be request body.

Comment: You might need to share the error message details if you want further help.

Comment: In the visual studio debugger it shoulds ("StatusCode: InternalServerError, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 122)

Comment: Compare calls made by Postman and by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Postman-Token" to just "token".  This worked for me on another project.  Keep in mind the request parameters change with every request.